# How to get final url from webview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I am making Downloader app which has a Webview where user can browse when there is the video playing he can download by click float button .but the problem is that it has only initial URL I want final URL to send it to my API to download that video.**How to get Final Url in webview**

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(myapp());
}
class myapp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _myappState createState() => _myappState();
}


final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
class _myappState extends State<myapp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: new Text('Fb Video Downloader'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(''),
            WebView(
              initialUrl: "https://example.com",
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webcontroller){
                _controller.complete(webcontroller);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [WebViewController](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController-class.html) it seems like it has a method called [currentUrl()](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController/currentUrl.html) that probably will give you the result you're looking for.

```
currentUrl = await _yourWebController.currentUrl()
```